# Access custom block in page.html.twig template

Tags: views, 8, theming, entities

I've added a custom block (which is an image) in the HEADER section of a view. I want to show this image at the top of my page but currently it appears in content **views-view.html.twig**.

How can I access to this image in **page.html.twig**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take away the block from the view header and use [twig_tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module to be able to insert something like this in your twig template

```
{# No need to configure this block on "admin/structure/block" page. #}
<dt>Block:</dt>
<dd>{{ drupal_block('BLOCKID') }}</dd>
```

Or if you don't want to use an extra module add to your THEMENAME.theme

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('BLOCKID');
  $content = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block')->view($block);
  $variables['my_block'] = $content;
}
```

and in your twig template just use

```
{{ my_block }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The first approach look better.